# JavaScript Accordion Menu works in IE not chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

The following code works great in IE but does nothing in chrome or firefox.

In Chrome just appends # on the end of the URL and blinks the screen. As if its is calling on that url. I know its an older script, it does exactly what I want in ie.
any help would be much appreciated.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function expandCollapse(elem, changeImage) {
 if (document.getElementById) {
ecBlock = document.getElementById(elem);
if (ecBlock != undefined && ecBlock != null) {
  if (changeImage) {
    //gets the image associated
    elemImage = document.getElementById(elem + "Image");
  }
  //make sure elemImage is good
  if (!changeImage || (elemImage != undefined && elemImage != null)) {
    if (ecBlock.currentStyle.display == "none" || ecBlock.currentStyle.display == null || ecBlock.currentStyle.display == "") {
      //shows the info.
      ecBlock.style.display = "block";
      if (changeImage) {
        //Just got in expanded mode. Thus, change image to "collapse"
        elemImage.src = "images/up.png";
      }
    }
    else if (ecBlock.currentStyle.display == "block") {
      //hide info
      ecBlock.style.display = "none";
      if (changeImage) {
        //Just got in collapsed mode. Thus, change image to "expand"
        elemImage.src = "images/down.png";
      }
    }
    else {
      //catch any weird circumstances.
      ecBlock.style.display = "block";
      if (changeImage) {
        elemImage.src = "images/up.png";
      }
    }
  }
  //end check elemImage
}
//end check ecBlock
  }
//end getElemById
//end expandCollapse function
</script>
```

and one of the lines I created are

```
<h4>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:expandCollapse('infoBlockID3', true); return false;"><img src="images/down.png" id="infoBlockID3Image" border="0" class="actionIcon" alt="How long will it take to hear fom an adjuster?" align=absmiddle>How long will it take to hear fom an adjuster?</a>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
    <span id="moreInfoContainer"></span>
    <noscript><ID id="moreInformation">How long will it take to hear fom an adjuster?           </ID></noscript>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</h4>

<div id="infoBlockID3" style="display: none" class='BodyText'>
  <p>2nd Line goes here
<ul>
  <li>Another Line</li>
  <li>Last Line</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>
```

Thank you so much for your help. This will help me tremendously, if I can get this tow work.

Comment: use jquery to make ur code browser independent . javascript code isn't browser independent.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome nor Firefox or any other browser other than Internet Explorer or Opera does not support the currentStyle property of an element.
In order to fix your issue, just replace 'currentStyle' with 'style':

```
if (ecBlock.currentStyle.display == "none" || ecBlock.currentStyle.display == null || ecBlock.currentStyle.display == "") {
```

should be

```
if (ecBlock.style.display == "none" || ecBlock.style.display == null || ecBlock.style.display == "") {
```

and

```
else if (ecBlock.currentStyle.display == "block") {
```

should be

```
else if (ecBlock.style.display == "block") {
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. I can't tell you how much I appreciated it!